# Handlebars access nested array values by index in placeholders

Tags: handlebars.js

I just begin with handlebars.js to render following json, but I am not sure how to access the values of nested json array using index.

[image]

Following is the template, I tried with `{{this.1}}` and `{{1}}`, but no luck

```
<div>{{name}}<div>
    {{#each params}}<div>
        <span>{{this.1}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{../id}}[]" value="{{this.0}}">
    </div>{{/each}}
</div></div>
```

Following is the JSON string, just in case:

```
{
    "id": 5753,
    "name": "Состав съемщиков",
    "params": [
      [15868, "Семья"],
      [15911, "Женщина"],
      [15913, "Мужчина"]
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to use the array index is in square brackets `[0]`, here is my working template:

```
<div>{{this.name}}<div>
    {{#each this.params}}<div>
        <span>{{this.[1]}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{../id}}[]" value="{{this.[0]}}">
    </div>{{/each}}
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can you adjust your JSON object?* If so here is something that I would try:

**Html body:**

```
  <h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
    <div>
      {{this.name}}
      <div>
        {{#each this.params}}
        <div>
          <span>{{this.txt}}</span>
          <input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{../id}}[]" value="{{this.id}}">
        </div>
       {{/each}}
      </div>
   </div>
   </script>
```

**index.js**

```
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
    "id": 5753,
    "name": "Состав съемщиков",
    "params": [
      {"id": "15868", "txt":"Семья"},
      {"id": "15911", "txt":"Женщина"},
      {"id": "15913", "txt":"Мужчина"}
    ]
}

$('body').append(template(data));
```

**Result:**

```
Handlebars JS Example
Состав съемщиков
<!-- these are checkboxes but I can't insert a picture.. -->
Семья  
Женщина  
Мужчина
```

I believe this is *due to your JSON object format*, below is a live example for the solution I just outlined:

```js
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
    "id": 5753,
    "name": "Состав съемщиков",
    "params": [
      {"id": "15868", "txt":"Семья"},
      {"id": "15911", "txt":"Женщина"},
      {"id": "15913", "txt":"Мужчина"}
    ]
  }

$('body').append(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
<div>{{this.name}}<div>
    {{#each this.params}}<div>
        <span>{{this.txt}}</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{../id}}[]" value="{{this.id}}">
    </div>{{/each}}
</div></div>
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps :)